# Nano sleep command in Perl

Tags: perl

Im trying a perl script with
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval usleep);

usleep(9.098888)
usleep(9.091111)

my script is containing, above commands also, I need a clarification that, 
how much round of usleep will do?
how to use nanosleep instead? (how much precition it would be in?)

Thanks in advance,
Saranyya

Comment: What architecture are you running on? There are inherent limits to different CPUs and OSes regardless of the application stack.

Comment: With 9 seconds of sleeping, your code is subject to timing jitters on the wakeup because of scheduling issues.

Comment: @Jonathan:  `usleep(9)` sleeps for 9 microseconds, not 9 seconds.  :-)

Comment: @Nemo: OK - 9 microseconds is also going to be subject to large jitters in the timing - proportionally bigger ones.  And the fractional microseconds (which threw me off) are definitely not very sensible.

Comment: Saranyya: what task are you trying to accomplish?  why do you need to sleep with such precision?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this depends on your platform.

On my own Linux system, Perl's `usleep` already calls `nanosleep`:

```
$ strace -- perl -le 'use Time::HiRes; Time::HiRes::usleep(1);' 2>&1 | tail
open("/usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter/Heavy.pm", O_RDONLY) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff375a5740) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(4, "package Exporter::Heavy;\n\nuse st"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "nd without a leading &.\n\t    # ("..., 4096) = 2250
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
nanosleep({0, 1000}, NULL)              = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

(Actually, I am pretty sure the C library's `usleep` calls `nanosleep` internally.)

The actual resolution you can expect depends on your specific platform.  These sleep functions can have a resolution measured in *milliseconds* (especially for long sleeps), and they always try to round up.

If you specify the exact version of your hardware and operating system, someone might be able to track down the effective resolution of `nanosleep` for you.

Comment: Is that the output of a debug build of Perl?